# How to select rows after last 10 records in php mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just want to know how to call  after 10 rows in `flash` column.
I want to call all `category = today`. Is it possible?

For Example

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE category='today' AND flash='true' limit 60
```

Comment: You should add sample data and sample result. This need clarifications

Comment: Can u post some sample data and desired output

Comment: What you are looking for is 'offset'.

Comment: Do you meant columns or rows? Nvm... I figured.

Comment: i want to call data after 10 records. my sample data is turkish codes. i thing you won't understand. if you still want to see it i will text it.

Comment: Do you want to remove the first 10 records `before` the `where clause` or after?

Comment: Yes @Italy i want to remove first 10 records but only "flash" records.

Comment: Really confusing and unclear !

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for (it's an official solution shown in the [MySQL SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#id4651990))?

```
SELECT * FROM news
WHERE flash='true'
LIMIT 10, 18446744073709551615;
```

**Update:**

After reading your comments, maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   `news`
        WHERE  (`flash` = 'true')
        LIMIT  10, 18446744073709551615) `after_flash`
WHERE  `after_flash`.`category` = 'today';
```

Comment: Nope. this one is also calling from flash and today. i want to call when the flash is 10. because in my page you can only see 10 flash news and i want to call the news at flash which is after 10.

Comment: @Italy : 

Thanks Dave. its an example that i want to do.

my database is like this.

"news" database -

id, title, spot, fulltext, category, photo, flash, status, hit...



im calling flash news from if "flash = true" 

than after another line im calling news from category if "today"


if category "today" and flash "true" it calls from both of them but i want to call flash after 10. could i explain??

Comment: @İsmailAltunören Of course you can! Add it to your question (there's a button like this, or you can use <ctrl+G>. BTW my name is Itay not Italy

Comment: Hahaha sorry ITAY.. i will try to send photo in 5 min. thank you very much.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kQCEq.jpg this is image. The news at “flash” can not be published at “category”. Some news at category at “flash” 
is also “today” . But i wrote if the flash is active dont show at category “today” in the codes
but i want to show when the “flash” news reach 10 records, at category section...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean fetch 60 records from positions 11-70?

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE category='today' AND flash='true' limit 10,60
```

You may need to do an ORDER BY clause as well to sort the data.

Comment: Thanks Dave. its an example that i want to do.

my database is like this.

"news" database -

id, title, spot, fulltext, category, photo, flash, status, hit...



im calling flash news from if "flash = true" 

than after another line im calling news from category if "today"


if category "today" and flash "true" it calls from both of them but i want to call flash after 10. could i explain??